# galaxy s6 build number LRX22G.G920W8VLU2A0G2 root help

Tags: rooting

Its been like 3 hours that I am looking about how to root this build number of my galaxy s6, I have found some links but I don't know whether they will work or not. Please can you tell which method will root the phone.

My phone details are
Android version 5.0.2
Build # LRX22G.G920W8VLU2A0G2

Methods I found to root phone are -

Method # 1. forum.   xda-developers.   com/show...&postcount=175 [ someone did root it with build number G920W8VLU1AOCG , mine is G920W8VLU2A0G2 so can I use his method over my build number? ] and cf auto root is only available for G920F (international version).

Method # 2. http://www.skipsoft.net/?page_id=1197

Method # 3. http://galaxys6root.highonandroid.co...twrp-recovery/

Please tell me which method should i use to root my galaxy s6.

Thank you very much.

Comment: can you please relink xda? also, most users a reporting success on 5.0.2 with the highonandroid method.